# LEFT JOIN help in sql

Tags: sql, postgresql, outer-join

I have to make a list of customer who do not have any invoice but have paid an invoice … maybe twice.

But with my code (stated below) it contains everything from the left join. However I only need the lines highlighted with green.

How should I make a table with only the 2 highlights?

[image]
[image]

```
Select paymentsfrombank.invoicenumber,paymentsfrombank.customer,paymentsfrombank.value
FROM paymentsfrombank
LEFT OUTER JOIN debtors
ON debtors.value = paymentsfrombank.value
```

Comment: You should probably join the tables on Invoice Number, not value.

Comment: So there is always an exact match? An invoice has only one or zero records in each table? If an invoice exists in both tables, the customer and amount are exactly the same?

Answer (score 1):

You only want to select columns from `paymentsfrombank`. So why do you even join?

```
select invoice_number, customer, value from paymentsfrombank
except
select invoice_number, customer, value from debtors;
```

(This requires exact matches as in your example, i.e. same amount for the invoice/customer).

Answer (score 0):

There are two issues in your SQL. First, you need to join on Invoice number, not on value, as joining on value is pointless. Second, you need to only pick those payments where there are no corresponding debts, i.e. when you left-join, the table on the right has "null" in the joining column.  The SQL would be something like this:

```
SELECT paymentsfrombank.invoicenumber,paymentsfrombank.customer,paymentsfrombank.value
FROM paymentsfrombank
LEFT OUTER JOIN debtors
ON debtors.InvoiceNumber = paymentsfrombank.InvoiceNumber
WHERE debtors.InvoiceNumber is NULL
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `NOT EXISTS` :

```
SELECT p.*
FROM paymentsfrombank p
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM debtors d WHERE d.invoice_number = p.invoice_number);
```

However, the `LEFT OUTER JOIN` would also work if you add filtered with `WHERE` Clause to filtered out only missing customers that haven't any invoice information :

```
SELECT p.invoicenumber, p.customer, p.value
FROM paymentsfrombank P LEFT OUTER JOIN 
     debtors d
     ON d.InvoiceNumber = p.InvoiceNumber
WHERE d.InvoiceNumber IS NULL;
```

Note : I have used table alias (`p` & `d`) that makes query to easier read & write.

Answer (score 0):

in mysql we usually have this way to flip the relation and extract the rows that dosen't have relation.
`Select paymentsfrombank.invoicenumber,paymentsfrombank.customer,paymentsfrombank.value
FROM paymentsfrombank
LEFT OUTER JOIN debtors
ON debtors.value = paymentsfrombank.value where debtors.value is null`